# Google Analytics don't show url parameters of campaign

Tags: url, google-analytics, prestashop, url-parameters

I'm working with an online shop made it with prestashop. When I access to an url of the site or with parameters of the site, this are reflected correctly in Google Analytics.

If I try to access to this url: https://www.calzadosniza.es/es/botas-y-botines-mujer I can see this url correctly in Google Analytics in real time:

[image]

If I apply a filter to the website, this generate a new url like this: https://www.calzadosniza.es/es/botas-y-botines-mujer?q=Marca-DR.MARTENS

Which I can see perfectly in Google Analytics:

[image]

But, If I try to acces to the site with an url parametrized with a campaign like this url:

https://www.calzadosniza.es/es/botas-y-botines-mujer?utm_source=googleAds&utm_medium=ad1&utm_campaign=inicio_mujer

If I check this url in Google Analytics in real time, I can see only the url without parameters:

[image]

If we check the url in the url bar of the browser, we can check that this appears with all the parameters:

[image]

Why happen this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Google Analytics removes the utm-parameters automatically from the URL. It stores the values in the Source-, Medium- and CampaignName-Dimensions respectively. So if you want to filter by any of the parameters just go to the "Traffic Sources" item in the menu, in the data table click the name of your source or medium and you will see that your realtime report get's filtered by the selected value (in the permanent reports you can do the same via filters or segments).

If GA kept the query parameters it would be unable to aggregate by url (each url with distinct parameters would be aggregated into it's own row), that's why they are cut off.

Comment: Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!! I have found now the parameteres in GA!!! Thanks!!!